# Filling in missing data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working in SQL Server. Suppose I have the following table:

```
3/1/2013    aaa   7     5
1/1/2013    bbb   1     2
10/10/2012  ccc   5     8
9/9/2012    ddd   6     9
8/8/2012    bbb   2     3
```

I would like to take the values from the "bbb" rows and propagate them upwards (ordering by date) essentially making:

```
3/1/2013    aaa   1     2
1/1/2013    bbb   1     2
10/10/2012  ccc   2     3
9/9/2012    ddd   2     3
8/8/2012    bbb   2     3
```

What is the best way to do this in SQL Server?

Comment: Do you want to update or just select?

Comment: I would like to just select

Comment: Am using SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something pretty basic could be

```
SELECT MT.Date, MT.Text, 
       CASE WHEN MT.Text = 'bbb' THEN Number
            ELSE (SELECT TOP 1 Number 
                               FROM MyTable MT2 
                               WHERE MT2.Date < MT.Date AND 
                                     MT2.Text = 'bbb'
                               ORDER BY MT2.Date DESC)
            END Number,
       CASE WHEN MT.Text = 'bbb' THEN Number2
            ELSE (SELECT TOP 1 Number2 
                               FROM MyTable MT2 
                               WHERE MT2.Date < MT.Date AND 
                                     MT2.Text = 'bbb'
                               ORDER BY MT2.Date DESC)
            END Number2 
       FROM MyTable MT
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cbee5/3

or using `OUTER APPLY` (it should be faster)

```
SELECT MT.Date, MT.Text, 
       CASE WHEN MT.Text = 'bbb' THEN MT.Number
            ELSE MT2.Number 
            END Number,
       CASE WHEN MT.Text = 'bbb' THEN MT.Number2
            ELSE MT2.Number2
            END Number2
       FROM MyTable MT
       OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 MT2.Number, MT2.Number2 
                                 FROM MyTable MT2
                                 WHERE MT.Text <> 'bbb' AND 
                                       MT2.Text = 'bbb' AND 
                                       MT2.Date < MT.Date
                                 ORDER BY MT2.Date DESC
                   ) MT2
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cbee5/7

Comment: Is this possible with a LEFT JOIN?

Comment: @Denis I think you would need a `CROSS APPLY`

Comment: @Denis But what you are looking for is probably described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045040/replace-null-values-with-latest-non-null-value-in-resultset-series-sql-server-2

Comment: I updated my question to show what I meant. I guess I could always just have 2 columns generated the way you suggested but doesn't sound efficient.

Comment: @Denis Changed the SELECTs, now with *more* columns :-)

Comment: this worked great! Thank you - I was thinking about this with partitioning but your way is much easier...

Comment: @Denis `CROSS APPLY` / `OUTER APPLY` are like `INNER` / `LEFT` joins where the joined "object" in some way depends for some "parameters" on the other tables. Here for example we have to compare with the `MT.Date`. Other "standard" uses are with table functions that require parameters.

Answer (score 1):

To select, you can go as simple as;

```
SELECT t1.date, t1.tag, t2.val, t2.val2
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table1 t2 
  ON t2.tag='bbb' AND t1.date >= t2.date
LEFT JOIN Table1 t3 ON t3.tag = 'bbb' AND t1.date >= t3.date AND t3.date > t2.date
WHERE t3.date IS NULL
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/27834/1).

Updating the content of the table, you can use pretty much the same query;

```sql
UPDATE t1
SET val=t2.val, val2=t2.val2
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table1 t2 
  ON t2.tag='bbb' AND t1.date >= t2.date
LEFT JOIN Table1 t3 ON t3.tag = 'bbb' AND t1.date >= t3.date AND t3.date > t2.date
WHERE t3.date IS NULL
```

[Another SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ab732/1).