# get previous value in place for null rows

Tags: mysql

Is there a way for me to get the previous value if the next row is null?
My database looks like this

```
|           tstamp      | val1 | val2 |
|   2015-01-21 01:00:00 | 15.2 | 25.1 |
|   2015-01-21 01:30:00 | null | null |
|   2015-01-21 02:00:00 | null | 14.1 |
|   2015-01-21 02:30:00 | 11.2 | null |
|   2015-01-21 03:00:00 | null | 21.1 |
|   2015-01-21 03:30:00 | 12.2 | 13.1 |
```

Currently the only query i have is only getting the last row which is 12.2 and 13.1

```
SELECT tstamp, val1, val2
FROM table
WHERE id IN (1,2) AND
tstamp  BETWEEN "2015-01-21 00:00:00" AND "2015-01-21 23:00:00"

GROUP BY DATE(tstamp), HOUR(tstamp), MINUTE(tstamp) DIV 30
ORDER BY tstamp DESC
LIMIT 1
```

My desired output is

If i use this the result I get is

```
|           tstamp      | val1 | val2 |
|   2015-01-21 01:00:00 | 15.2 | 25.1 |
|   2015-01-21 01:30:00 | 15.2 | 25.1 |
|   2015-01-21 02:00:00 | 15.2 | 14.1 |
|   2015-01-21 02:30:00 | 11.2 | 14.1 |
|   2015-01-21 03:00:00 | 11.2 | 21.1 |
|   2015-01-21 03:30:00 | 12.2 | 13.1 |
```

Is there a way I can get this to work?

Thank You.

Comment: Yes like for 1:30 and 2:00 i want to get the last value which is from 1:00 = 15.2 and then for the next null 3:00 i want to get the value from 2:30 which is 11.2

Comment: Same for the val2 column, the value on 1:30 should be the value from 1:00 and then on  2:30 the value should be from 2:00

Comment: val1 would be the MIN column and val2 would be MAX

Comment: like low and high on a stock market?

Comment: So you might end up with a 'low' that's actually higher than its 'high' ?!?!?

Comment: What about values between  23:00:00 and 23:59:59?

Answer (score 4):

```
select
    tstamp,
    if(val1 is null,@prevVal1,@prevVal1:=val1),
    if(val2 is null,@prevVal2,@prevVal2:=val2)
from t;
```

The := operator assigns a value to a variable as well as returning that value.

Comment: You need to assign the vars too

Comment: @Strawberry - I'm not sure I follow.  Variables are being assigned.

Comment: But they're not initialized. And I think you meant "val2"

Comment: They could be initialized in a previous query to a desired value if desired.  If not initialized they will return null, which could conceivably be a desired result if the first values aren't present.

Comment: @strawberry it's cool. If the first row doesn't have a value, you'll get a null because the UDV is unassigned. Sounds reasonable.

Comment: I would use `coalesce(var1, @...)`

Comment: @Bohemian. No. They need to be initialized in order to return the OP's desired result.

Comment: im not sure about setting up a variable, cause the value is not fixed.. its different everyday...

Comment: If you have a persistent connection and worried about a variables value at the end of one query affecting the next, initializing it as strawberry mentioned, will ensure that doesn't happen.

Comment: @atxdba Unless it's initialized, it WILL NOT return the correct result!! (and technically, it needs an order by clause too)

Comment: i think im doing it wrong, i tried it but i think its getting the value from the other column, like for example on Val2 at 2:30, instead of getting the value 14.1 i got 11.2.... what i did was i used COALESCE and did it like COALESCE((case when id = 1 THEN val1 END), @var1 := val1)

Answer (score 2):

Adapting atxdba's otherwise excellent solution...

```
SELECT tstamp 
     , IF(val1 is null,@prevVal1,@prevVal1:=val1)
     , if(val2 is null,@prevVal2,@prevVal2:=val2) 
  from my_table
     , (SELECT @preVal1:=null,@preVal2:=null) vars
  ORDER 
     BY tstamp;
```

Comment: Is it possible to replace null value with next value instead of previous value?